# Constructing an If statement based on the return of the environment $PATH piped through grep (with bash)

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep, environment-variables, pipe

**I've answered my own question in writing this, but it might be helpful for others as I couldn't find a straightforward answer anywhere else. Please delete if inappropriate.**

I'm trying to construct an if statement depending whether some `<STRING>` is found inside the environment `$PATH`.

When I pipe $PATH through grep I get a successful hit:

```
echo $PATH | grep -i "<STRING>"
```

But I was really struggling to find the syntax required to construct an if statement around this. It appears that the line below works. I know that the `$(...)` essentially passes the internal commands to the if statement, but I'm not sure why the `[[...]]` double brackets are needed:

```
if [[ $(echo $PATH | grep -i "<STRING>") ]]; then echo "HEY"; fi
```

Maybe someone could explain that for me to have a better understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: `$( )` captures the output of a command, the `[[ ]]` is the improved version of the old `[ ]` or `test` command, which can do regrexp pattern matching with by the `=~`  pattern operator and much more. see `help [[`, also you don't need `grep` for that , just do `[[ $PATH = *'string*' ]]` or the regex `[[ $PATH =~ string ]]` also the `[[ ]]` is not part of the `if` statement, there is also a `nocaseglob` and `nocasematch` for case insensitive pattern match.

Comment: For a discussion of `if` statements in their various forms and how `[` and `[[` are used, you might find [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306115/53604discussion) of mine helpful.

Comment: Both these comments really helped in my understanding of ```[``` and ```[[```.

I can confirm that both ```[[ $PATH = *'string'* ]]``` and ```[[ $PATH =~ string ]]``` work, although there was a typo in the first option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make better use of shell syntax. Something like this:

```
$ STRING="bin"
$ grep -i $STRING <<< $PATH && echo "HEY"
```

That is: first, save the search string in a variable (which I called `STRING` so it's easy to remember), and use that as the search pattern. Then, use the `<<<` redirection to input a "here string" - namely, the `PATH` variable.

Or, if you don't want a variable for the string:

```
$ grep -i "bin" <<< $PATH && echo "HEY"
```

Then, the construct `&& <some other command>` means: IF the exit status of `grep` is 0 (meaning at least one successful match), THEN execute the "other command" (otherwise do nothing - just exit as soon as `grep` completes). This is the more common, more natural form of an "if... then..." statement, exactly of the kind you were trying to write.

Question for you though. Why the `-i` flag? That means "case independent matching". But in Unix and Linux file names, command names, etc. are case sensitive. Why do you care if the PATH matches the string `BIN`? It will, because `bin` is somewhere on the path, but if you then search for the `BIN` directory you won't find one. (The more interesting question is - how to match complete words only, so that for example to match `bin`, a directory name `bin` should be present; `sbin` shouldn't match `bin`. But that's about writing regular expressions - not quite what you were asking about.)

The following version - which doesn't even use `grep` - is based on the same idea, but it won't do case insensitive matching:

```
$ [[ $PATH == *$STRING* ]] && echo "HEY"
```

`[[ ... ]]` evaluates a Boolean expression (here, an equality using the * wildcard on the right-hand side); if true, `&&` causes the execution of the `echo` command.

Comment: Apologies, the '-i' wan't important. It was copied from another line of code I had and hadn't removed it.

In your example above, should it be ```[[ $PATH =~ *$STRING* ]]```?

I think the solutions that aren't using grep are more elegant.

Comment: @llionevans - either `[[ $PATH == *$STRING* ]]` as I wrote it, or `[[ $PATH =~ $STRING ]]`. The `=~` operator is for matching regular expressions (not that different from `grep`). The `*` in my version is *globbing* - somewhat similar to regular expression matching, but still a different thing, and subject to different operators (`==` rather than `=~`). Regular expressions are much more powerful and flexible than globbing, but for that very reason, slower. If globbing can do it, I'll use it, and use regexp only when really needed.

Comment: for some particular reason '==' didn't seem to work for me which is why I mentioned it (probably specific to the string I had). Unfortunately the subtleties of the various approaches are mostly lost on me, but I get to understand a bit more with each 'challenge'.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use [[ ]], just:

```
if echo $PATH | grep -qi "<STRING>"; then echo "HEY"; fi
```